# Is it possible to delete all traces and files on a mac?

Tags: privacy, forensics, macos, deletion, data-recovery

Is it possible to delete all traces and files on a mac, so no one can recover files and there will be no traces at all for this files or any activity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reliably erase all information on a hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/how-can-i-reliably-erase-all-information-on-a-hard-drive)

Comment: This question has been answered several times on the site. Search "secure erase SSD".

Comment: @binarym is it the same for all operating systems?

Comment: Or this one too: [SSD erasure strategy for a secondhand laptop](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176303/ssd-erasure-strategy-for-a-secondhand-laptop)